# AAD user extension properties using Microsoft graph client sdk

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to fetch the extension properties of the user added in Azure active directory using the Microsoft GraphClient sdk.

ie, I need the result of the command below using Graph client.

Using Microsoft.Graph, Version=3.4.0.0.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId 50413382@wingtiptoys.com |select -ExpandProperty 
ExtensionProperty

Key                                                             Value
---                                                             -----
odata.metadata                                                  https://graph.windows.net/d29b7a9b- 
6edb-4720-99a8-3c5c6c3eeeb0/$metadata#directoryObjects/@Element
odata.type                                                      Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User
createdDateTime
employeeId                                                      50413382
onPremisesDistinguishedName
thumbnailPhoto@odata.mediaEditLink                              directoryObjects/8cc715a1-0698-4d1a- 
8f49-441a84b6dbc4/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User/thumbnailPhoto
thumbnailPhoto@odata.mediaContentType                           image/Jpeg
userIdentities                                                  []
extension_10a03227b5f146ad8a0087cf0bafd627_division             
|30103611|50435526|50230396|10192257|86009851
extension_10a03227b5f146ad8a0087cf0bafd627_company              wingtiptoys Inc.
extension_10a03227b5f146ad8a0087cf0bafd627_extensionAttribute10 GF
extension_10a03227b5f146ad8a0087cf0bafd627_employeeID           50413382
extension_10a03227b5f146ad8a0087cf0bafd627_cn                   50413382
extension_10a03227b5f146ad8a0087cf0bafd627_extensionAttribute8  wingtiptoys Inc. Inc.
extension_10a03227b5f146ad8a0087cf0bafd627_extensionAttribute7  Chuck
extension_10a03227b5f146ad8a0087cf0bafd627_extensionAttribute6  US11
extension_10a03227b5f146ad8a0087cf0bafd627_extensionAttribute5  US1-Rochester, NY- Site
extension_10a03227b5f146ad8a0087cf0bafd627_extensionAttribute4  USC
extension_10a03227b5f146ad8a0087cf0bafd627_extensionAttribute2  Regular
extension_10a03227b5f146ad8a0087cf0bafd627_employeeType         ARR
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Sumith, please refer to the solution I provided below. If it helps your problem, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance~

Comment: Perfect. It worked!!!. Thanks for the clear explanation @Hury Shen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem, we need to know one thing before do it.

The powershell command request the "**Azure AD graph api**" in the backend but not "**Microsoft graph api**" because we can see the host is `https://graph.windows.net....`. If use "**Microsoft graph api**", it should be `https://graph.microsoft.com...`.

The extension you request can just access by "**Azure AD graph api**" but can not access by "**Microsoft graph api**" although there is a property like `extension` in the response of "**Microsoft graph api**(get user)". So we need to use Azure AD graph SDK but not use `Microsoft.Graph`.

According to search on internet, very little information can be found about how to use Azure AD graph SDK. And the latest version of the sdk updated on `10/17/2016` because Microsoft hasn't updated "Azure AD graph" for a long time. I'm not clear how to use Azure AD graph SDK, so I suggest you to request the Azure AD graph api directly in your code. You can refer to my solution below:

**1.** You need to register a app in your AD and add the permission to it(add Azure AD graph permission but not Microsoft graph permission).

[image]

[image]

**2.** After that, we can request the Azure AD graph api by the code below:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp25
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            //request for the access token
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "client_id", "<client_id>" },
                { "scope", "https://graph.windows.net/.default" },
                { "client_secret", "<client_secret>" },
                { "grant_type", "client_credentials" },
            };
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
            var response = await client.PostAsync("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/token", content);
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            //parse the responseString and get the access_token in it
            dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);
            var token = json.access_token;

            //use the access token to request the azure ad graph api
            HttpClient client1 = new HttpClient();
            client1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            var response1 = await client1.GetAsync("https://graph.windows.net/<tenant_id>/users/hury@xxx.onmicrosoft.com?api-version=1.6");
            var responseString1 = await response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Console.WriteLine(responseString1);
        }
    }
}
```

The `responseString1` contains all of the fields of the user, you need to parse the json and get the extension you want.